# Error accessing Neo4J Browser online. I get ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

I have a Neo4J EC2 instance on AWS.  I am able to access it programmatically, but when I try to access the Neo4J browser I get the error listed above.  The URL I am using currently is:

http://35.174.211.60:7474/browser/

From there, I get the following page:
[image: Neo4J Browser]

This page then tries to call the following URL:
bolt://35.174.211.60:7687
I use the username (neo4j) and password that already allows my code to access the Neo4J programmatically.  From here I get the following error:

> ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver.

I have verified that ports 7474, 7473, and 7687 are open to all in my EC2 Neo4J instance.  What should I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the fix suggested by [this Knowledge Base article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-websocket-connection-failure/):

> This error can be resolved by editing the file
>   $NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf and uncommenting:
>
> ```
> #To have Bolt accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
> dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687
> ```

Comment: Hello @cybersam, how can we access to dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687 in a Neo4j VM ?

Comment: You should submit a new question with full details about your VM, what you have tried, and what exactly is not working.